# What is the best practice for calling Moodle Web service endpoints in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, rest, moodle-api

I created a moodle application using Moodle's web service. I wrote the repository code like this, what needs to be improved so that it is easier to maintain later on

```
 Future<List<UserModel>> getEnrolledUsers(String token, int courseId) async {
    String baseUrl =
        "https://lms.pptik.id/webservice/rest/server.php/?wstoken=$token&wsfunction=core_enrol_get_enrolled_users&moodlewsrestformat=json&courseid=$courseId";

    Uri url = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
    final response = await client.get(url);
    final List result = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
    inspect(result);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (result.isEmpty) {
        return <UserModel>[];
      }
      return result.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

as I know, api calls usually use the body for the parameters, but when I tried to use the Moodle api, I was confused especially if the endpoint requires an array parameter.  So I need a best practice for calling the Moodle api.